# Passing string iterator to function

Tags: c++, string, pointers, iterator

I have a function I want to use in other function which gets number from string.
In base funcion I create `std::string::iterator` and I want to pass it to other function that gets this number, skips spaces, and then outer function continues to search through string.

When I am using iterator I do something like `*strPtr` to get value, and `*++strPtr` to get value and move to another character. When I pass pointer to that I need to use `**strPtr` to get value and I hove no idea how to get value and increment iterator. :(

I did `*++*strPtr` and it kinda worked but it crashes when it quits internal function.

```
double calculate( char* x ){
std::string formula = x;
ValueStack valueStack;
OperatorStack operatorStack;

std::string::iterator strPtr = formula.begin();

while( *strPtr == ' ' )
{
    strPtr++;
}

if( *strPtr == '-' )
{
    std::string temp;
    temp += *strPtr;

    while( *++strPtr == ' ' );

    while( ((*strPtr <= '9' ) && (*strPtr >= '0' )) || (*strPtr == '.') )
    {
        temp += *strPtr;
        while( *++strPtr == ' ' );
    }

    char** x;
    valueStack.push( strtod( temp.c_str(), x ) );
}

while( strPtr < formula.end() )
{

    if( *strPtr == ' ' )
    {
        while( *++strPtr == ' ' );
    }

    if( operatorStack.isOper( *strPtr ) )
    {   
        if( *strPtr == ')' )
        {
            evaluate( &valueStack, &operatorStack );
            strPtr++;
        }

        else if( *strPtr == '(' )
        {
            operatorStack.push( *strPtr );

            while( *++strPtr == ' ' );

            if( *strPtr == '-' )
            {
                std::string temp;
                temp += *strPtr;

                while( *++strPtr == ' ' );

                while( ((*strPtr <= '9' ) && (*strPtr >= '0' )) || (*strPtr == '.') )
                {
                    temp += *strPtr;
                    while( *++strPtr == ' ' );
                }

                char** x;
                valueStack.push( strtod( temp.c_str(), x ) );
            }
        }

        else if( operatorStack.prior( *strPtr ) <= operatorStack.prior( operatorStack.top() ) )
        {
            evaluate( &valueStack, &operatorStack );
            operatorStack.push( *strPtr++ );
        }

        else operatorStack.push( *strPtr++ );
    }

    else
    {
        std::string temp;
        temp += *strPtr;

        while( *++strPtr == ' ' );

        while( ((*strPtr <= '9' ) && (*strPtr >= '0' )) || (*strPtr == '.') )
        {
            temp += *strPtr;
            while( *++strPtr == ' ' );
        }

        char** x;
        valueStack.push( strtod( temp.c_str(), x ) );
    }
}

evaluate( &valueStack, &operatorStack );

double ret = valueStack.pop();
if( pow(ret, 2) < 0.000000001 ) return 0;
return ret; 
}
```

To clarify, I want make function like this, and use it above:

```
void getValue( std::string::iterator strPtr, ValueStack* valueStack )
{
std::string temp;
    temp += *strPtr;

    while( *++strPtr == ' ' );

    while( ((*strPtr <= '9' ) && (*strPtr >= '0' )) || (*strPtr == '.') )
    {
        temp += *strPtr;
        while( *++strPtr == ' ' );
    }

    char** x;
    valueStack->push( strtod( temp.c_str(), x ) );
}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see exactly what you are doing

Comment: We don't know what `evaluate` is doing.  Therefore you need to either provide all the code, or remove the calls to functions we do not know about and recreate the issue.

Comment: `valueStack.push( strtod( temp.c_str(), x ) );` is accessing an uninitialized variable `x`. This may crash your program because the `strtod` function dereferences `x` also. Read the documentation of `strtod` to see how to use it properly.

Comment: @Matt McNabb THANK YOU! It was causing a problem :)

Comment: @Pershing that's good; you still do have to check you didn't hit `end()` *every time* you do `++` on the iterator though.

Answer (score 0):

There are an easier way for iterating over a `string` you can, for instance:

```
    string str("3+5-4   -  3 / 4");

    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it!=str.end();++it)
    {
        if (!(*it == ' ')) {  // Skip spaces.

           if(isdigit(*it))
           {
             // Do your thing with ValueStack.
           }
           else
           {
               // Handle operators here.
               switch(*it)
               {
                   case('-'): break;
                   case('+'): break;
                   case('/'): break;
                   case('*'): break;
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, I recommend you take a look at [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). It will help you to achive what you're trying to do (evaluating mathematical expressions) in a more elegant way. Also in that link there are an example of a "calculator" just like you want but using `spirit`.

Your algorithm only supports one digit numbers. And its very hard to get multi-digit numbers supported without using some external library (such as `Boost.Spirit` for instance ;) ).

Comment: Thank you. It's purposed to calculate more complexed equations including negatives, floating point, and brackets. It works in this form, but I've wanted to call one function three or four times instead of putting quite long code this many times.

Comment: So, if its working what's wrong with the `evaluate` function? Why you don't use it?

Comment: It works. Maybe I didn't make it clear. I want to close the second part in other function and call it, for example `getValue`

Comment: @Pershing - `It's purposed to calculate more complexed equations including negatives, floating point, and brackets.` The issue with writing your code in the way you wrote it is that you will quickly go bonkers trying to enhance and maintain it. Your code will be doing all sorts of twists and turns trying to keep up. The formal way of writing such expression evaluators is using a grammar/parser or as stated, a library that implements this paradigm, and not do "character-by-character" looping in an adhoc fashion.

Comment: Thank you all for answering, I really apreciate that and it helps me a lot. But the question was: how do I pass an iterator into function to make it works and don't working on its copy which I think is the problem?

Comment: @Pershing - Maybe you're falling into the trap of the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You want to keep trying your "solution" of "passing iterators" until you get it to work. But maybe your solution is not the best way (as suggested by others). Maybe you can just pass the entire string and iterate over it. I don't know, since I don't quite fully understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well it goes like this. There is certain point in my string I find a number. From now one I want to call a function which gets that number and push it to the `valueStack` then it leaves and searching goes on just from the place after that number. It works that way but there are 3 cases where I can find number. Instead on putting rather long code in there I want to write function and call it 3 times. It is what I am still asking about. I know my techniqe could be better, but that's not the case here. I can live with that solution, it works well, but I wanted to kinda improve that.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see in your code is that you assume that std::string is null terminated.  Most of your loops are not bounded properly.  For example:

```
while( *strPtr == ' ' )
{
    strPtr++;
}
```

What if the entire string is spaces?  What stops this loop from going into uncharted territory?

A std::string does not have to be null terminated, so there is no guarantee this loop will stop when it reaches the end of the string.  You do the same sort of loop in other places in your code.

If you're going to loop this way, it would need to be written:

```
while( *strPtr == ' ' && strPtr != formula.end())
    strPtr++;
```

Comment: That's why I suggest iterating with the `for` loop `for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it!=str.end();++it)`. Actually, this code has many errors, and the main cause is the extensive use of `*` and `++`. There is no need to complicate such trivial work.

Comment: Thank you. I've added some safety features :)